# Sh: php command not found when trying to execute file from web broeser

Tags: command-line, server, php

I have one file with code

```
shell_exec (php test.php)
```

When I run this file from command prompt, It run successfully and when same file I am trying to run through web browser this will give error as

```
sh: php command not found.
```

what can be the issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you do run this file through the web browser? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The browser shouldn't be running anything through `sh`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the path for `php` isn't in the `$PATH` environment variable used for `shell_exec` when you are running it from the web server.

Use the full path for the `php` command, like

```
shell_exec (/usr/bin/php test.php)
```

You can use the `which` command on the command prompt to find the full path for `php`

```
which php
```

Comment: This is correct but my code is going to deploy on various server so can not hardcode the path. can you please tell me the way where I will get /user/bin/php path dynamically in php code.